# Biblatex in Beamer doesn't work unless backened=bibtex8 is provided

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibtex

I have `ref.bib` and want to cite some papers at the end of the slides. So far I know I should use `\footfullcite{key}` with `\usepackage{biblatex}` and the references would be shown at the end of the slide. However, doing pdflatex bibtex pdflatex in my texMaker. Specifically, when running bibtex will give the following :

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016) The top-level auxiliary
>   file: mwe.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file
>   mwe.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file mwe.aux I
>   found no \bibstyle command---while reading file mwe.aux (There were 3
>   error messages)

adding [backend=bibtex8] will work although it gives warning 'functionality may be reduced'

My question is how to place citations bottom of the slide with biblatex without resorting to biber in texmaker

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{ref}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello. \footfullcite{key}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `biblatex` uses the Biber back-end as standard: if you don't give an option, it will write no data for BibTeX to the `.aux` file.

Comment: Either you use BibTeX (or BibTeX8) and give the `backend=bibtex` (or `bibtex8`) option in which case you will have to live with reduced functionality. Or you use Biber (in that case you can add the option `backend=biber` or leave the option out altogether, Biber is the default) and get the full set of features. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help with Biber in your editor.

Comment: @moewe Thank you. The linked question solved my issue. Many *much* million and billion thanks. I am voting to close the question because it is actually asking how to link biber instead of bibtex.